# How to perform lag/lead operation on data stored in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Is it possible to perform lag, lead operations on the data stored in Hive ?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you need to use the [SQLWindowing](https://github.com/hbutani/SQLWindowing/wiki) extensions to perform lag, lead, and other windowing functions.

In the future, this will be moved into Hive (see [HIVE-896](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-896)), and the syntax will change slightly.

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah Peschka for your quick reply and it was a gr8 help... I have a table say Test with two columns A and B. Now how can i find Lag ? Can give some example for finding Lag using SQLWindowing?

Comment: There are a number of examples using LAG in the SQLWindowing wiki page. See https://github.com/hbutani/SQLWindowing/wiki#topn-leadlag

Answer (score 2):

You can get previous time stamp by using LAG function Example is below:

```
NVL( LAG (currentTimestamp, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [partinioned columns] ORDER BY currentTimestamp ASC)  , 0 ) AS previousTimestamp;
```

Same Like LEAD also here by default one row
NVL( LEAD (currentTimestamp, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [partinioned columns] ORDER BY currentTimestamp ASC)  , 0 ) AS NextTimestamp;